# C++ Growth of containers containing containers?

Tags: c++, stl, containers

If I have a `std::vector<std::set<int>>`. The vector will reallocate if you insert past its capacity. In the case where you have another resizable type inside the vector, is the vector only holding a pointer to the said type?

In particular I want to know about how memory is allocated if a vector is holding an arbitrary type.

```
std::vector<int> a(10); //Size will be sizeof(int) * 10
std::vector<std::set<int>> b(10);
b[0] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, .... }; //Is b's size effected by the sets inside?
```

Comment: `std::set` is movable, or what are you asking about?

Comment: you are mixing the terms. The size of a vector is the number of elements it holds. In your example the size of `b` is 10 and it does not change

Comment: Not necessarily std::set. If I have a vector<map>, vector<vector>, and the type being contained changes in size, does the main vector grow? How do I know it won't. How does the compiler decide?

Comment: Nope the main vector doesn't grow when a contained type is resized. The vector only allocates memory for what it knows about at compile time, so this doesn't include any dynamically allocated memory by an element itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memory that any vector will allocate "by itself" will always be sizeof(element_type) * vector.size().

The vector can only allocate memory for element data that is visible at *compile time*. It doesn't care about any allocations done by the element class.

Think of a vector as an array on steroids. Like an array, a vector consists of a contiguous block of memory where all elements have the same size. To fullfill this requirement it must know at compile time how big each element will be.

Imagine a std::set to have these member variables:

```
struct SomeSet
{
   size_t size;
   SomeMagicInternalType* data;
};
```

So no matter how `data` will be allocated *at runtime*, the vector only allocates memory per element for what it knows at *compile time*:

sizeof(SomeSet::size) + sizeof(SomeSet::data)

Which would be 4 + 4 on a 32-bit machine.

Comment: I see so the part I'm worried about getting bigger is on the heap.

Answer (score 3):

C++ objects can only have one size, but may include pointers to arbitrarily sized heap memory. So, yes, container objects themselves generally include a pointer to heap memory and probably don't include any actual items. (The only typical exception is string types, which sometimes have a "small string optimization" that allows string objects to contain small strings directly in the object without allocating heap memory.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {     
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::cout << sizeof(v) << "\n";
    std::cout << v.size()  << "\n";

    v.push_back(3);
    std::cout << sizeof(v) << "\n";
    std::cout << v.size()  << "\n";     
}
```

The exact number may differ, but I get as output:

```
24
0
24
1
```

The size (size=size of the object) of a `vector` does not change when you add an element. The same is true for a `set`, thus a `vector<set>` does not need to reallocate if one of its elements adds or removes an element.

A set does not store its elements as members, otherwise sets with different number of elements would be different types. They are stored on the heap and as such do not contribute to the size of the `set` directly.

Answer (score 0):

A `std::vector<T>` holds objects of type `T`. When it gets resized it copies or moves those objects as needed. A `std::vector<std::set<int>>` is no different; it holds objects of type `std::set<int>`.